# What is Container as a Service

Tags: docker

What is a Container as a Service (CaaS) means in general terminology. I found Kubernetes, Docker provide these services. But, what does that mean?

Does Container mean it provides the different OS platform to deploy our code to work?

Comment: https://www.scalyr.com/blog/containers-as-a-service-complete-guide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, as seen in dockercon [here](https://twitter.com/BettyJunod/status/666529772743360512), that docker provides a set of services (a **Service Platform**) around containers for:

- **building**,
- **shipping** and
- **running**:

[image: caas]

[Building and shipping can be either](https://twitter.com/AdrienBlind/status/666545870654021632):

- to a **data center**
- to a **cloud**:

[image: caas targets]

It means you combine Iaas and PaaS into a Caas: Infrastructure + Platform.

[image: caas]

<sup>(Source: [Hyper.sh blog](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjABahUKEwiahcy--5nJAhXHDxoKHVrhAsA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhyper.sh%2Fblog%2F&usg=AFQjCNHDcuKmnLbIz-tKu3G-FFLzUrmf3Q&sig2=3DWtHCuHPirl-yoHTUyyKg), currently unavailable, from Thibault Bronchain)</sup>

The term CaaS [was seen](https://twitter.com/docker/status/625143613333352448) in [GOTO conference: Patterns for Docker Success • Simon Eskildsen (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnIiFWD7yUw).

Answer (score 0):

You take your container and put them in that service and you don't care about the server and network structure behind them. For that Google use Kubernetes. So if you want yes. You can deploy your container on different services if you want.

On AWS you can do the same and deploy your container with the AWS Container service.

https://aws.amazon.com/de/documentation/ecs/

Answer (score 0):

In short words: CaaS allows any Docker container to run on provider platform.