# Docker how to create container

Tags: docker, containers

I would like to make a container, which contains ubuntu that will be installed postgresql

how to make a docker like that?

1 Container contains

```
Images 1: ubuntu
images 2: postgresql
```

or

1 Container contains

```
Images 1: ubuntu + postgresql
```

If one of my assumptions above is true, how do I make?
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [postgres dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/ed23320582f4ec5b0e5e35c99d98966dacbc6ed8/9.4/Dockerfile), it starts with

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

If you *really* need an Ubuntu distro, you could make your own, starting with

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
```

In any case, you would end with one postgres image built on top of a Linux distro (meaning your second assumption is accurate).

As mentioned in "[How does a Docker image work?](https://docs.docker.com/engine/introduction/understanding-docker/#how-does-a-docker-image-work)"

> Each image consists of a series of layers.
>   **Docker makes use of [union file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) to combine these layers into a *single* image**.
>   Union file systems allow files and directories of separate file systems, known as branches, to be transparently overlaid, forming a single coherent file system.

Comment: Untuk mengetahui lebih lanjut tentang UFS dan lapisan , Anda dapat membaca http://pierre-jean.baraud.fr/blog/2014/05/14/fist-look-dockerfile/

Comment: Saya ingin membuat container yang berisikan OS ubuntu yang diinstall postgresql, apakah saya bisa untuk menggabungkan 1 container 2 images, 1 images untuk OS, 1 images untuk postgresql

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto 
Anda bisa melakukan itu, seperti yang saya sebutkan dalam jawaban saya: mencoba Dockerfile dimulai dengan `FROM ubuntu: 15.10`. Ini akan men-download gambar ubuntu, dan Anda akan membangun satu gambar tunggal menggabungkan kedua.

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Itu berarti ubuntu gambar sudah ada: Anda tidak harus membangun. Hal ini sudah tersedia di registri publik Docker Hub.

Comment: Saya sudah menambahkan images ubuntu, namun versi 14.04, dengan perintah : sudo docker pull ubuntu:14.04

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Ya, secara default, buruh pelabuhan menarik ubuntu 14.04, LTS terbaru (Long Term Support). Anda dapat menarik tag specifc (tercantum dalam https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/): tarik ubuntu: 15.10. Ini adalah praktek terbaik untuk "memperbaiki" versi yang ingin Anda gunakan.

Comment: Kemudian saya mencoba menginstall postgresql-9.3 didalamnya, tapi saya coba untuk keluar container, terus kemudian masuk kembali, postgresql yang saya install hilang. Bisa dibantu dijelaskan kenapa?
Dan
Docker itu sendiri, apakah berjalan dalam kernel?
Hardware > OS > Docker .
konsep Docker : Docker = images > Container .

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto 
Terima kasih. Jangan lupa http://stackoverflow.com/a/33887463/6309 juga.